# script -e and crontab or at

Tags: bash, script, time, cron, at

I have a shellscript I want to run via at and use script to capture a transcript.  script -e was introduced in util-linux-ng 2.18 and returns the retval of the child process.

I want to capture the return value of the command I execute through script, and react accordingly.

```
$ cat /tmp/b.sh 
#!/bin/bash

script -qea /tmp/out.txt -c asdfl

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    touch /tmp/RET0
else
    touch /tmp/RETNOT0
fi

$ /tmp/b.sh 
bash: asdfl: command not found
$ ls /tmp/RETNOT0 
/tmp/RETNOT0
```

I expect the outcome above because "asdf1" isn't a valid command.

However, if I run the same shell script through at or crontab, the return value is zero.

```
$ crontab -l
40 17 * * * /tmp/b.sh

$ ls /tmp/RET0 
/tmp/RET0
```

Can someone help me understand why this happens, and how I can get the correct return value?